# MySQL trigger and values not supplied in update query

Tags: mysql, mariadb

there is a way in mysql / mariadb triggers to know if a value is present  (set) in the update query?

```
For example:

    create table MyTest (
    col1 varchar(45),
    col2 varchar(45)
);

insert into MyTest values ( 'val1','val2');
```

So when I execute

```
update MyTest set col1 = 'val1.1'
```

in the trigger I would like to know that *col2* is not set.

Thank You

**UPDATE** (I changed also table schema for better explain my problem)

I have setup a trigger like this

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `MyTest_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `MyTest` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF (NEW.col2 <=> OLD.col2) THEN
        SET NEW.col2 = 'triggered';
    END IF;
END
```

If I call

```
UPDATE MyTest set col1 = 'val1.3'
```

table will be (this is ok)

```
+------+---------+
|col1  | col2    |
+------+---------+
|val1.3|triggered|
+------+---------+
```

but if i call

```
UPDATE MyTest SET col1='val1.4',col2='val2.4'
```

first time table is ok

```
+------+---------+
|col1  | col2    |
+------+---------+
|val1.4|val2.4   |
+------+---------+
```

but a second update like this

```
UPDATE MyTest SET col1='val1.5',col2='2.4'
```

table will be:

```
+------+---------+
|col1  | col2    |
+------+---------+
|val1.5|triggered|
+------+---------+
```

instead i would like it should be

```
+------+---------+
|col1  | col2    |
+------+---------+
|val1.5|val2.4   |
+------+---------+
```

There is some way  i can check this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Boolean expression

```
NEW.col2 <=> OLD.col2
```

can be used in an `IF` statement (or elsewhere).  Notes:

- It tests for whether `col2` is *changing*, it does not test whether you *specified* `col2` without changing it.
- `NULL` is properly handled because of the `<=>` operator.

**UPDATE** (based on further details)  See if this comes closer:

```
IF ( NEW.col1 <=> OLD.col1  -- testing only col1 for changes
 AND NEW.col2 IS NULL)      -- avoiding clobbering col2
    NEW.col2 = 'triggered';
```

(You haven't yet specified enough use cases to provide a complete solution, but maybe I have given you enough building blocks?)

Comment: I have updated my question with example because this isn't working the way I need.

Comment: If `col2` is declared `NULL`, what do you want?

Comment: (Updated my answer)

Comment: Sorry, I already tested vs NULL, but this doesn't work...
`NEW.col2` is never set to 'triggered'

I think that if a column isn't set, in the trigger NEW.col is set equal to OLD.col